# Allowing further overriding of save_formset on a ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Pretty basic usage scenario here. I want to save the user who created an object and the user who last modified it. However, it's an inlined model so I, of course need to use `save_formset`. The Django docs have the following example code:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```

The thing is, if you notice, since `super` is never called, this is a dead-end. If the `ModelAdmin` is subclassed and this method is overridden in the same way, you lose the functionality inherent in the parent. This matters because this is such a common usage scenario that I want to factor out the functionality, so I created the following:

```
class TrackableInlineAdminMixin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            if hasattr(instance, 'created_by') and hasattr(instance, 'modified_by'):
                if not instance.pk:
                    instance.created_by = request.user
                instance.modified_by = request.user
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
        super(TrackableInlineAdminMixin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

I tacked on the call to `super` out of habit more than anything else, not thinking that it actually will cause the formset to save twice. Nevertheless, it still works in every scenario except one: deleting. As soon as you try to delete an inline in the admin, you get an error. The error's pretty vague and not really relavent to my question here, but I believe it's related to trying to save the formset again after you've just deleted one of the instances in it. The code works just fine when the call to `super` is removed.

Long and short, is there any way that I'm missing to both customize the formset saving behavior *and* allow subclasses to do their own overriding?

Comment: Just found [a unsolved ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17988) for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a doozie.

I had some fun poking around and it appears all of the action happens here in `django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet`.

The problem is that `ModelFormSet.save()` deletes instances regardless of of the `commit` flag and does not modify the forms to reflect the deleted state.

If you call `save()` again it iterates over the forms and in `ModelChoiceField` cleaning tries to pull up the referenced ID and throws an invalid choice error.

```
def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
    self.changed_objects = []
    self.deleted_objects = []
    if not self.initial_forms:
        return []

    saved_instances = []
    for form in self.initial_forms:
        pk_name = self._pk_field.name
        raw_pk_value = form._raw_value(pk_name)

        # clean() for different types of PK fields can sometimes return
        # the model instance, and sometimes the PK. Handle either.
        pk_value = form.fields[pk_name].clean(raw_pk_value) 
        pk_value = getattr(pk_value, 'pk', pk_value)

        obj = self._existing_object(pk_value)
        if self.can_delete and self._should_delete_form(form):
            self.deleted_objects.append(obj)
            obj.delete()  
            # problem here causes `clean` 6 lines up to fail next round

            # patched line here for future save()
            # to not attempt a second delete
            self.forms.remove(form)
```

The only way I was able to fix this is to patch `BaseModelFormset.save_existing_objects` to remove the form from `self.forms` if an object is deleted.

Did some testing and there doesn't appear to be any ill effects.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough analysis. I just wanted a sanity check to make sure I wasn't just completely missing something, but if a patch is required to the Django source, then this does seem like a prime candidate for a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work for me in Django 1.5 but based on this solution I was able to override the same method with a try-except to avoid the error in "clean()" https://gist.github.com/anibalpacheco/96f5537490adc782892da265332f7f8e

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Pratt helped:

> I tacked on the call to super out of habit more than anything else,
>   not thinking that it actually will cause the formset to save twice.

I was trying to further override a `save_formset` in order to send a post save signal. I just could not understand that calling `super()` was only saving the formset for second time.

In order to deal with the `super()` issue, I created a `save_formset_now` method with my custom code, that I call when I override the `save_formset` through the `admin.ModelAdmin` children.

This is the code, which seems to also take care of the deleting issue, using Django 1.10 in 2016.

```
class BaseMixinAdmin(object):
    def save_formset_now(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        for instance in instances:
            # *** Start Coding for Custom Needs ***
                ....
            # *** End Coding for Custom Needs ***
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()

class BaseAdmin(BaseMixinAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        self.save_formset_now(request, form, formset, change)


class ChildAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        self.save_formset_now(request, form, formset, change)
        my_signal.send(...)
```